# Core Data save closure

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, closures, codable

I'm rebuilding application to store requests in `Core Data`, and now all requests have completion closure (it should be called after a success response from server).

Is it possible to store that closure in `Core Data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you can somehow convert the closures into instances of `Data`. Core Data won't save them directly, but it will save anything that you can convert to and from `Data`. I don't know how you'd do that, but that's how it would have to work.

Really it's almost the same problem as if you weren't using Core Data-- how would you save them to *anything*? Other persistence methods would have similar requirements, that you manage to serialize and deserialize the closure.

Most likely what you need to do is, instead of saving the closures, save enough data that you can reconstruct the closures when you run the requests. How hard that is depends on the details of what the closures do.

Comment: In Core Data there Transformable type for properties. I can save dictionary to that property and I can save a closure to the dictionary. Can't I do that? (because closure is just a compiled code and it's like unnamed function, so may be there is a way to remember a pointer to a closure, may be I can do that my storing closure in a dictionary?

Comment: You can only store a dictionary if it’s limited to certain specific data types or if you convert it to a data object yourself. Closures are not one of those types. Storing a pointer doesn’t help unless the app keeps  running until you need the pointer, because pointers are addresses in memory that won’t be valid if the app exits

Comment: And even if the app doesn’t exit before needing those pointers, they’re still only useful if you can ensure that the closures still exist in memory by maintaining a strong reference to them. But if you do that you don’t need to use Core Data or other data persistence, since you already have the data in memory.